# Constraint Layout não consegue se alinhar ao canto da tela - bottom of

Tags: android, android-layout, constraint

Olá, tenho um Layout .xml que tem um texto como parâmetro e que no canto inferior direito dessa tela deveria ser exibido um Floating Action Button, como mostrado no layout preview abaixo
O que na prática não acontece, pois, na prática o FAB não só não se mantém na borda da tela, como também sobrepõe o texto exibido, isso só aconteceu após atualizar a versão do Constraint no builde.gradle, o que pode ter sido?

.xml do Layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_cadastroBoi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/vermelho3"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addAlgo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_unique_ox"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:backgroundTint="#fffff9"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="60dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_addBoiLote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#212121"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Adicionar boi sem Bluetooth"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/addBoiSemBlue"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addBoiSemBlue" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addBoiSemBlue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ox_unique"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="56dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_addBoi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#212121"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Adicionar boi via Bluetooth"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/addBovinoBle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addBovinoBle" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addBovinoBle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ox_unique_ble"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:maxImageSize="60dp"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/454213/edit) a pergunta para colocar o código do `.xml`. Provavelmente isso ocorre porque o `ConstraintLayout` não está ocupando a tela inteira. Quanto ao FAB ficar na frente do texto, até onde entendo esse é o comportamento esperado.

Comment: Editado, então só tem como colocar na borda da tela se o textView ocupar todo o espaço?

Comment: Por quê -1? A pergunta está correta...

Answer (score 1):

Na caso do primeiro, você está alinhando o topo do Fab com a base do texto:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_cadastroBoi"
```

Alinhe com o parent:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

---

No caso do segundo, você está alinhando o FAB com itens que não é o parent:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addBovinoBle" 
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_cadastroBoi"
```

Para o canto inferior direito seria:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Aí só definir as margens.

Comment: No caso `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"` não "deve" ser parent, pois o topo bloquearia o bottom, isso meio que trava o FAB no canto fora da tela, vou tentar algo parecido, obrigado!

Comment: Opa, foi mal.. layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf.. vou corrigir a resposta

Comment: Obtive o mesmo resultado, por enquanto, mas acho que o caminho é esse que você disse mesmo

Comment: Faz igual o segundo, apaga qualquer outro constraint, deixa só os dois, Bottom e end.

Comment: Acho que tem a ver com de fato o tamanho do meu texto, pois quanto mais texto eu coloco, mais os botoes "baixam", mas com textos curtos eles nunca ficam de fato no canto, é estranho

Comment: É como se mesmo definindo o Constraint como match_parent o aparelho ainda enxergue ele como Wrap_content, isso tá muito bugado kkkkk

Comment: Olha se ainda tem referência com o texto, como está setado ao parent, não deveria interferir

Comment: Como você poder na atualizacao do .xml, mesmo assim, continua o mesmo resultado, sinceramente já estou extremamente confuso kkkkk

Comment: [Match_parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603751/set-width-to-match-constraints-in-constraintlayout) não funciona com Constraint Layout como pai... Que confusão do Google

Comment: Pro MatchParent funcionar você precisa fazer o constraint dos dois lados, EndToEnd StartToStart

Answer (score -1):

Os constraints layouts têm os maravilhosos Vertical e Horizontal guidelines, que pode restringir a posição do elemento onde for preciso, usei um único Vertical Guideline e adicionei os parâmetros da resposta do Rogerio Santos e consegui o resultado perfeito, mesmo quando gira a tela. 
[image: example]

[Referência](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) sobre os guidelines